# Excel Sheet Data Retrieval

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is my first post here so hopefully I am doing this correctly.
I have a multi-sheet workbook.

Sheet 1 is Codes with 3 columns.
Sheet 2 Data has 3 columns.
Sheet 3 I would like to retrieve all row data based on ***any*** matches of codes in column A of sheet 1, Codes, such as 100,113,114,115. So it would basically look like:
[Screenshot of information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or0t1.jpg)

So basically I could have a sheet for each of my Codes columns to help organize their data automatically.

Comment: Hi Will, welcome to Superuser. I'm having trouble visualizing your setup, can you please be a bit more descriptive?

Comment: Sorry. I have a multi-sheet workbook in Excel 2013. The first sheet has a listing of codes in 3 columns. The first column is Low Risk Fire with 100,113,114,115. The second column has Mod/High Risk Fire with 111,112, the third column has ARFF with 135, 462. The second sheet has Call Data. One of the columns for it is incident type, which is the same as the codes on sheet 1. So, in the next sheet titled Report I want to bring in any calls that meet criteria in column 1 of the Codes sheet. I want to bring the row information on the Call Data sheet into the Report sheet for any matches.

Comment: I am unable to attach the actual spreadsheet because of my rating  it seems, so I tried to attach a screenshot of each sheets information in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, your second sheet seems to be near your final product. You just need to apply a filter to the codes that you want to view. No need for a sheet 3. If you want to make your "report" look fancier you could pivot the data and use slicers to filter your data.

As for sheet 1 not sure you need that also, unless you want to add a column in sheet 2 to identify the code to the type of fire. In this case I would change sheet one to have the first column be the list of codes and the second column to be the type of fire. Then you can add a vlookup formula to the second sheet to get the type of fire based on the code.

Hope this gets you in the right direction.

Comment: I appreciate the fast responses. PT doesn't really work as they are wanting to slice the data onto several different sheets for their report. I found some VBA code and am looking at creating a helper column for the VL function. So that's a better start than before. Again, thank you.